What is "broadcasting"?
Is "broadcasting" in the context of tensors, vectors, and matrices a mathematical term, or one only used in computer engineering? Who coined this term?

I think the term originated from message-passing context of parallel computing architectures.

Here's a wikipedia article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_(parallel_pattern)

Array broadcasting does not make much sense outside the context of Array programming, so I doubt this term originated in mathematics. Probably, one of the array programming languages/libraries used the term first. MATLAB and R do not seem to use this term. Julia does, although I do not know whether the usage is earlier than NumPy.
